# facebook link posting is not showing thumbnail image using C# SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, thumbnails

I used below code to post a link using C# SDK

```
var client = new FacebookClient(this._accessToken);
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "In House testing ";
parameters.link = "code.gigyonline.com";
parameters.picture = "lonnnnnnnnnng image path/EM10000_thumbnail.jpg";
parameters.name = "My Post";
parameters.caption = "My Post Caption";
parameters.description = "Nothing now";
dynamic result = client.Post("{page ID}/feed", parameters);
```

Above post is working fine except for the thumbnail image. Then I assume that the image url length may be too long, so I created a short url still it is not showing the thumbnail image.

So  my new picture url changed as below

```
parameters.picture = "http://www.cprpt.com/L/3e39fd3";
```

1. Any advise to resolve this issue will be appreciated
2. Also do we have any url length restriction for posting a thumbnail image for a link

Comment: Do we have any rules for posting a thumbnail image for a post from C# SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is not at the long image path I believe. It just depends upon the image size you are using for thumbnail. I used another small image with the lengthy path it is working .

Always  think that is a thumbnail image and select image accordingly :)